# How to parallel process files recieved in a zip file format?

Tags: scala, apache-camel

As part of an adapter service we are building for a client, we need to process XMLs received in a zip file from a third party service and post it in JSON format to another API. Everything works fine unless we introduce parallel processing for the XMLs. This is the code we are using to read the XML files in the zip.

```
this.basicRoute
  .log("picked file fileName=${file:absolute.path}")
  .choice(when(ex => ex.getIn.getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME_ONLY).toString.matches(".*\\.zip"))
    .log("inside zip file processing zipFileName=${file:absolute.path}")
    .unmarshal(zipFile)
    .split(_.getIn.getBody)
      .streaming()
      .when(_.getIn.getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME).toString.matches(".*\\.xml"))
      .setBody(ex => InputStreamToXmlConverter.toXml(ex.getIn.getBody.asInstanceOf[InputStream]))
      .choice(when(exchange => XmlValidator.isProperLocale(exchange.getIn.getBody.asInstanceOf[Node]))
        .to("direct:toPath"))
      .otherwise()
        .to("file:" + Settings("some.ignoredPath")))
```

We tried a couple of approaches for parallel processing the files but get a "Stream Closed" exception.

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.ensureOpen(ZipInputStream.java:66) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:181) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:273) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:175) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1$$anonfun$apply$mcI$sp$1.apply$mcI$sp(BufferedSource.scala:38) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.io.Codec.wrap(Codec.scala:68) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:38) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.io.BufferedSource$$anonfun$iter$1.apply(BufferedSource.scala:38) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$9.next(Iterator.scala:162) ~[scala-library.jar:0.12.1]
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$17.hasNext(Iterator.scala:511) ~[scala-library.jar:0.12.1]
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327) ~[scala-library.jar:0.12.1]
at scala.io.Source.hasNext(Source.scala:226) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727) ~[scala-library.jar:0.12.1]
at scala.io.Source.foreach(Source.scala:178) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.addString(TraversableOnce.scala:320) ~[scala-library.jar:0.12.1]
at scala.io.Source.addString(Source.scala:178) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:286) ~[scala-library.jar:0.12.1]
at scala.io.Source.mkString(Source.scala:178) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:288) ~[scala-library.jar:0.12.1]
at scala.io.Source.mkString(Source.scala:178) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.mkString(TraversableOnce.scala:290) ~[scala-library.jar:0.12.1]
at scala.io.Source.mkString(Source.scala:178) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

Any help on how to deal with this problem will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you considered to send the unzipped messages to a seda: endpoint and implement parallel processing from there, as a second route?

Answer (score 0):

I am not fluent at all with the Scala DSL but, isn't an ending parenthesis missing on line:

```
.choice(when(ex => ex.getIn.getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME_ONLY).toString.matches(".*\\.zip"))
```

Comment: The parenthesis for the choice statement is closed at the last line.